# Method spreadsheets.batchUpdate doen't work with API Key

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

Method BatchUpdate just doesn't work with API Key auth. 
Response:

```
    {   "error": {
           "code": 401,
           "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
           "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"   
        } 
    }
```

[Try this API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) with API Key doesn't work too.
I didn't find anything about that. What's going on?

Comment: Although API key can use GET method, unfortunately, POST and PUT methods cannot be used by the API key. ``spreadsheets.batchUpdate`` uses POST method. So when you use this, please use OAuth2 and service account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)  states

> Authorization Scopes
>   Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

You error

> "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."

States that you are required to be authenticated and that Oauth 2 access token is required.

You said you tried with API key.  API keys are used for accessing PUBLIC data.  In order to access private data you need to be authenticated.  Which is what the documentation stated.

In order for that try me to work you will need to use `Google OAuth 2.0`.

Comment: It's clear. But in this case, why "Try this API" part contains option API Key?

Comment: Try me is all over the Google documentation this is a **default feature**.  That does not mean that API key is supported by All of the method in googles documentation.   Google assumes that you read the documentation page next to the Try Me and know that you need to use Oauth2 to authenticate.